# How to be able to find folders whose name keeps changing in shell/bash?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

So I'm looking for a way for my shell to find the folder with the code behind the folder name that keeps changing, in the data/app/ folder, for example the folder "com.tencent.ig-yHGLSvh42dYO-GNMFS9WxA==". Which always changes only in the part after "com.tencent.ig-", the second "-" and "==". Full path "data/app/com.tencent.ig-yHGLSvh42dYO-GNMFS9WxA==/"

Code that can find the location of a folder so I can change the contents of that folder. If possible the code is contained in a variable so I can use it like so:

```
findfolder = (Code)؜
؜printf $findfolder
```

Comment: It might be more fruitful to figure out why the folder name keeps changing, and fix that instead. (I assume the folder is created as part of some build process, and you're getting a default name based on something being hashed. Perhaps you can modify something to *always* use the same output folder name instead.)

Comment: In my opinion, why does the name of the folder always change after the application is closed or my cellphone is restarted, maybe it's an anti-cheat game or something like that. I don't really know

Comment: Could be a temporary directory whose name is generated to avoid conflicting with another directory, in which case why do you need to access a temporary folder managed by another program?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the parent directory to `./com.tencent.ig-....` or better yet, the full path. Good luck.

Comment: `findfolder=(com.tencent.ig-*-*==); printf '%s\n' "${findfolder[@]}"`

Comment: So, to clarify, you are saying that the program **assigns a new random name** for its session work file *every time it starts*.  Correct?  You are **NOT** saying that the program takes the file from the previous session and *renaming that to the new name*. Correct?

Comment: Yes, Its random name and not from previous session. The full path is "/data/app/com.tencent.ig-yHGLSvh42dYO-GNMFS9WxA=="